# FileMaker PHP API newEditCommand() not found..?

Tags: filemaker

Here's what I'm working with...

```
$FindInvoiceRecord = $FMInvoices->newFindCommand('Data Entry (XGA)');
$FindInvoiceRecord->addFindCriterion('InvoiceNumber', $InvoiceNumber);
$FindInvoiceRecord->setScript('wa_CommitRecord');
$FindInvoiceRecordResult = $FindInvoiceRecord->execute();
$FoundRecords = $FindInvoiceRecordResult->getRecords();

$FMInvoiceRecordID = $FoundRecords[0]->getField('zRecordID');
$OriginalInvoiceNotes = $FoundRecords[0]->getField('InternalNotes');
```

This works fine and loads my data as expected from the FileMaker record.  Then I'm trying to update the record...

```
$InvoiceUpdateData = array('InternalNotes' => $NewInvoiceNotes);
$InvoiceUpdateRecord = $FoundRecords[0]->newEditCommand('Data Entry (XGA)', $FMInvoiceRecordID, $InvoiceUpdateData);
$InvoiceUpdateRecordResult = $InvoiceUpdateRecord->execute();
```

But this is telling me that newEditCommand() method is not found..??  Any information on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newEditCommand is a method in the record object, not the result object.
Try this:

```
$InvoiceUpdateRecord = $FMInvoices->newEditCommand('Data Entry (XGA)', $FMInvoiceRecordID, $InvoiceUpdateData);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that did it!

Comment: Cool. I would suggest you check out the chapter on the PHP API in Filemaker's guide on custom web publishing for good info. Here is the link for version 16. FileMaker hasn't changed the PHP API for years, so it should be relevant for just about any earlier version also. https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fms16_cwp_guide.pdf